# color overlapping when drawing multiple path

Tags: android, canvas, drawing

**ArrayList**

```
ArrayList<Pair<Path, Float>> foregroundPaths = new ArrayList<Pair<Path, Float>>();
```

**Paint initilization**

```
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(0x0FFF0000);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.BEVEL);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(Math.abs(ImageViewTouch.brushSize
                    / getScale()));

    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP));

    mPaint.setAlpha(0x80);
```

**OnDraw**

```
  canvas.save();


    displayRectF = new RectF();


    canvas.concat(getDisplayMatrix());

    rect = canvas.getClipBounds();
    displayRectF.set(rect);

    for (Pair<Path, Float> p : foregroundPaths) {
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(p.second);
        canvas.drawPath(p.first, mPaint);
    }



    canvas.restore();
```

[image]

Above codes are capable of drawing on canvas using finger. But the problem is when multiple path crossing each other its overlap. I have attached a link of my app snapshot.
Overlapping is inside the green rectangle. I set Xfermode to paint but not working as i expect.

Please help me and suggest me, what should i do to remove this problem. 
any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: tried the below?. does it work for you?

Comment: why did you unaccept all of a sudden

Comment: even with this  mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
its the same story. doe snot solve. So i guess my answer in this context is right.

Comment: its not solution but you pointed out the cause. So, may be some one confused if i up vote this answer.

Comment: Issue resolve just need to add xfermode and some other stuff Thanks

Comment: @raviroshan Could you provide some code to see how you solved it?

Comment: downvoted because not providing the code which solved the issue. I think it not fair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new AvoidXfermode(Color.RED, 90, Mode.AVOID));
```

**it works for me.**

Comment: AvoidXfermode was deprecated in API level 16

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried:

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR));
```

After all what you want is an exclusive OR (XOR) - either the first line or the second line, but not both on top of each other.

I have not tried this, just seems like the logical answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @PieterGoosen I'm sorry, but as far as I see my answer directly related to the original question. ravi roshan asked how to avoid overlapping of two paths when it's semitransparent and using PorterDuff.Mode.OVERLAY mode is exactly for that. If you think that I didn't understand the question please correct me.

Answer (score 0):

Since AvoidXferMode is depreciated, this would be helpful for people who are using API 16+. This is rather like a workaround. But works perfectly fine. This overlapping error occurs because of the alpha value set for paint.

For eg., If you want to use 'Red' color with alpha
Instead of passing mPaint.setAlpha(), you could actually use utility function to set transparency to 'Red' color.

So in this case, just use mPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(getTransparentColor(Color.Red, 50))); and don't use setAlpha.

Use below code to get transparent color.

```
public static String getTransparentColor (int colorCode, int transCode) {
        // convert color code into hexa string and remove starting 2 digit

        String color = defaultColor;
        try{
            color = Integer.toHexString(colorCode).toUpperCase().substring(2);
        }catch (Exception ignored){}

        if (!color.isEmpty() && transCode < 100) {
            if (color.trim().length() == 6) {
                return "#" + convert(transCode) + color;
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Color is already with transparency");
                return convert(transCode) + color;
            }
        }
        // if color is empty or any other problem occur then we return deafult color;
        return "#" + Integer.toHexString(defaultColorID).toUpperCase().substring(2);
    }

  /**
     * This method convert numver into hexa number or we can say transparent code
     *
     * @param trans number of transparency you want
     * @return it return hex decimal number or transparency code
     */
    public static String convert(int trans) {
        String hexString = Integer.toHexString(Math.round(255 * trans / 100));
        return (hexString.length() < 2 ? "0" : "") + hexString;
    }
```

**Note:**
Even after all these changes if overlapping error occurs, then add the below code.

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I used:

```
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OVER));
```

It allows to draw pixels over the destination pixels without making path transparent.